# Not able to detect contour not more than one color

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am doing gesture recognition using color detection using opencv and python. The problem I am having is that contours are detected for only one color for example red, but the other two colors are not detected example green or blue, so my some gestures are not working.

In my code only red colour contours are detected and not blue

Code:

```
 import cv2
 import numpy as np
 from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
 import wx
 import time
 import pyautogui

 mouse = Controller()
 app = wx.App(False)
 (sx, sy) = wx.GetDisplaySize()(camx, camy) = (320, 240)
##green
 lowerBoundG = np.array ([65, 66, 77])
 upperBoundG = np.array ([96, 255, 255])
##red
 lowerBoundR = np.array ([134, 94, 98])
 upperBoundR = np.array ([179, 255, 255])
##blue
 lowerBoundB = np.array ([88, 78, 20])
 upperBoundB = np.array ([128, 255, 255])
 cam = cv2.VideoCapture (0)
 cam.set (3, camx)
 cam.set (4, camy)
 kernelOpen = np.ones ((5, 5))
 kernelClose = np.ones ((20, 20))
 mLocOld = np.array ([0, 0])
 mouseLoc = np.array ([0, 0]) DampingFactor = 3 while True
:
 ret, uf = cam.read()
 img = cv2.flip (uf, 1)
#convert BGR to HSV
 imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
#create the Mask
  maskG = cv2.inRange (imgHSV, lowerBoundG, upperBoundG)
  maskR = cv2.inRange (imgHSV, lowerBoundR, upperBoundR)
  maskB = cv2.inRange (imgHSV, lowerBoundR, upperBoundB)
#morphology
  maskOpenG = cv2.morphologyEx(maskG, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernelOpen)
  maskCloseG = cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpenG, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernelClose)
  maskOpenR = cv2.morphologyEx(maskR, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernelOpen)
  maskCloseR = cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpenR, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernelClose)
  maskOpenB = cv2.morphologyEx(maskB, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernelOpen)
  maskCloseB = cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpenB, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernelClose)
  maskFinalG = maskCloseG
  maskFinalR = maskCloseR
  maskFinalB = maskCloseB
  contsG, h = cv2.findContours(maskFinalG.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
             cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 
  contsR, v = cv2.findContours (maskFinalR.copy (), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
             cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 
  contsB, p = cv2.findContours (maskFinalB.copy (), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
             cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
##for COntrolling mouse cursor
  if (len (contsR) == 1):
     x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contsR[0])
     cv2.rectangle (img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
     cx = int (x + w / 2)
     cy = int (y + h / 2)
     div = int (w + h / 4)
     cv2.circle (img, (cx, cy), div, (0, 0, 255), 2)
     mouseLoc = mLocOld + ((cx, cy) - mLocOld) / DampingFactor
     mouse.position = (mouseLoc[0] * sx / camx, mouseLoc[1] * sy / camy)
     mLocOld = mouseLoc
##For Mouse right click
  elif (len (contsR) == 1 and len (contsB) == 1):
     mouse.click (Button.right, 1) time.sleep (1) cv2.imshow ("cam", img)
     ##cv2.imshow("mask",maskClose)
 cv2.waitKey (5)
```

Comment: Can you provide example image? Also try to fix the formatting of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code says:

```
##for COntrolling mouse cursor
 if (len (contsR) == 1):
 # [.....]
##For Mouse right click
  elif (len (contsR) == 1 and len (contsB) == 1):
```

If red has any value, the `elif` will never be reached, because the `if` is executed.

Instead, first try the case with more conditions:

```
##For Mouse right click
 if (len (contsR) == 1 and len (contsB) == 1):
 # [.....]
##for COntrolling mouse cursor
  elif (len (contsR) == 1):
```

So, if there is red and blue, do mouseclick. If there is no blue, but there is red, move cursor.

Comment: thank you so much. My code is finally working. I was trying to figure out this since so many days. Thank you